# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 changing marker and add satellite view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need help adding two things.

var image = '1368298974442034922android-car-home-256-th.png';
I would like to remove the red default marker and add this item

And i dont know how to change this from map to satellite view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info windows</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      .content 
      {
          width:75%;
          height:45px;
          overflow:scroll;  
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.3135749,-95.3050332);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Here It Is!</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      'Acording to our records it looks like your item is located with in a few feet of here.<br><br> Need more info check out this info. <br> <a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a></div>'+
      '</div>';


  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Here Is Where We Found It!'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Here Is Where We Found It!',
    icon: "1368298974442034922android-car-home-256-th.png"
});
```

Satellite View:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};
```